# TFS [merge] tag meaning in a code review of a merge

Tags: c#, tfs, merge

In the code reviews that i saw the files almost always have some merge tags in right of the file name e.g.

```
filename.cs [merge, edit]
filename.cs [merge, delete]
filename.cs [merge, branch]
```

What means when the file names with only merge inside the brackets?

e.g.

```
filename.cs [merge]
```

To be honest I don't know the real meaning of none of the tags above for sure, but I dont have any clue about the meaning of the last one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In TFS, if it shows [merge,edit] which mean it contains two status of this file, [merge] status and [edit] status.

- [**merge**] status for the unchanged file but have a merge action
- [**merge,edit**] status for the files in target updated with source
  content
- [**merge branch**] for the new add item in target, which copied from
  source
- [**merge,delete**] delete file in target
- [**merge,undelete**] undelete file in target
- [**merge,rename**] rename file in target
- [**merge,rename,edit**] rename a file in target and update its contents

Never see a [**merge, add**] status, this can't be combined.

Comment: My mistake, the file that i saw with 'add' have only the tag [add] without 'merge'

Answer (score 2):

As far as it appears to me, this means that file was included to merged changeset, but not actually changed.

Considering the first 4 tags:

- `add` - file has been added to source branch in merged changeset, hence -> added to target branch during merge
- `edit` - file content is changed
- `delete` - file has been deleted in source branch in merged changeset, hence -> deleted in target branch during merge
- `branch` - file has been checked-out (changed) in source branch in merged changeset, but is absent in target branch => hence file is branched